# Agregar diferentes atributos con mismos valores en XML C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net, xml

¡Hola! Es primera vez participando en un foro.

Estoy creando un archivo *.xml*, en el que tiene como entradas un arreglo bidimensional y un directorio. Lo que hace a continuación es enlistar atributos y valores respectivamente. Por medio de herencia, en un foreach asigno a un elemento en especifico las listas anteriores, mi código:

```
 public void AddElement(string[,] Array2D, string xmlpath)
        {
            var xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.Load(xmlpath);
            int index = 0, middle;
            List<string> list_attributes, list_values;

            try
            {
                int attributes = Array2D.GetLength(0);
                int values = Array2D.GetLength(1);

                string[] Array1D = new string[attributes * values];
                for (int v = 0; v < values; v++)
                {
                    for (int a = 0; a < attributes; a++)
                    {
                        Array1D[index] = Array2D[a, v];
                        index++;
                    }
                }

                middle = Array1D.Length / 2;
                list_attributes = Array1D.Take(middle).ToList();
                list_values = Array1D.Skip(middle).ToList();

                List<GetXML> Data = AddInfo(list_attributes, list_values);

                XmlNode nodeParent = xml.SelectSingleNode("//Parent");
                var nodeChild = xml.CreateElement("Child");
                nodeParent.AppendChild(nodeChild);

                foreach (GetXML info in Data)
                {
                    var attribute = xml.CreateAttribute(info.Attribute);
                    attribute.Value = info.Value;
                    nodeChild.Attributes.Append(attribute);
                }
                xml.Save(xmlpath);
                Console.WriteLine(xml.OuterXml);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

        }
```

El array de entrada es el siguiente:

```
string[,] Data = { { "FirstAttribute", "a" } ,{ "SecondAttribute", "b" } };
```

Y me resulta el *xml* así:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Root>
  <Parent>
   <Child FirstAttribute="a" SecondAttribute="b" />
  </Parent>
</Root>
```

El problema es que, cuando los valores son los mismos, no inserta el último atributo ni su valor. Los datos son:

```
string[,] Data = { { "FirstAttribute", "a" } ,{ "SecondAttribute", "a" } };
```

Generando el xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Root>
  <Parent>
    <Child FirstAttribute="a" />
  </Parent>
</Root>
```

¿Alguien sabe a qué se debe esa mala asignación?
De antemano, gracias.

Comment: Muy buen planteo de la pregunta!! solo como nota, mira porfa el [tour] y tambien [ask].. tene en cuenta, que esto no es un foro ;) es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas!!!

Comment: ¡Gracias por la corrección!

Comment: Ponle un punto de interrupción en el foreach y verifica que esté recorriendo todos los atributos, si pudieras compartir tu clase completa  (solo veo fracciones de codigo que no son suficientes para poderte ayudar) y la version de framework que usas también sería de gran ayuda, saludos!

Comment: Bien, agregué el método completo en la pregunta. Y si, estoy usando el **.Net Framework 4.5**. De hecho había recorrido la lista con diferentes métodos, y en todos me muestra los elementos que debe tener, solo pasa eso cuando los valores son iguales. Gracias, ¡saludos!